# VIM with graphical menu on windows

Tags: vim

Is there a way to have a VIM editor on Windows 8.1 displaying a graphical menu like File, Edit,etc...?
I need to be able to run VIM as Administrator, and then I need to be able to choose what file to open, so having a File menu item would be very helpful

Comment: `:set guioptions+=m` ??

Comment: The DEFAULT installer, with the DEFAULT selections, will give this to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program you are looking for is called gVim and is available for windows. However, you don't need a graphical menu to open a file in vim. For example

```
:e file
```

or

```
:o file
```

should both work fine without any graphical menus.